# How to compile linux kernel module?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module

I need to generate oops linux kernel error. I am using linux-3.13.3 and launching it on qemu. I found a following code which should cause the oops error:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>

static int crash_module_init(void)

{
     printk(KERN_INFO "crash module starting\n");
     int *p = 0;

     printk("%d\n", *p);

     return 0;
}

static void crash_module_exit(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "crash module exiting\n");
}

module_init(crash_module_init);
module_exit(crash_module_exit);
```

and I used the following Makefile:

```
obj-m = hello.o
KVERSION = $(shell uname -r)
all:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(KVERSION)/build M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(KVERSION)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

Unfortunately on qemu there's no such directory as  /lib/modules/3.13.3/build. There is only /lib/modules/3.2.0-4-686-pae and inside some directories (but no build). Even when I tried to put there one of the existing directory I got: "No rule to make target `modules`".

Can somebody tell me how to compile this module? Or maybe someone has another idea how to generate oops error? I would be very grateful.

Comment: How did you get kernel 3.13.3 on this system? Did you compile it yourself?

Answer (score 0):

My can check this [answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/5230/getting-no-rule-to-make-target-modules-stop-error-when-running-makefile-w) should help you solve your make issue

Check out [sysrq](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysrq.txt) for generating oops. Generally used to crash system when it seems to be in a livelock, but can crash it anyways. I am not sure if it works with Qemu.